# Add text in particular cell when focus on particular cell

Tags: excel, vba

How can you add text in cell C18 when I have my "focus" (so when I clicked this cell) on cell E18 ?
I tried some code combinations when searching here on other questions but nothing happens.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim myCell As Range:    Set myCell = ws.Range("E18")
    Dim iSect As Range

    Set iSect = Application.Intersect(Target, myCell)

    'If the selection is not your cell, exit sub
    If iSect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Range("$C$18").Value = "HERE IS THE TEXT I WANT"

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code looks ok. Have you placed it in the correct sheet module and checked that `application.enableevents=true`?

Comment: Try `If Not iSect Is Nothing Then Range("$C$18").Value = "HERE IS THE TEXT I WANT" End If` Also `Set ws = ActiveSheet`

Comment: Can you not just use something like `If Target.Address(false,false) = "E18" Then Range("C18").Value2 = "HERE IS THE TEXT I WANT"` - don't need to test for a selection range if you just want to click on cell `E18` and have something happen.

Comment: Is this code is the first Worksheet of the Workbook (i.e. in `ws`)?  You might want to consider the special object `Me` - e.g. `Set myCell = Me.Range("E18")` will make it Cell E18 of *the Worksheet that the code is in*.

Comment: @jamheadart That's fine for individual cells, but what happens if you select the Range C17:F20 (multi-cell selection), or if you want to run the code for a Range of different cells?  In both examples, `Application.Intersect` is a better choice

Comment: "don't need to test for a selection range if you just want to click on cell E18 and have something happen"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my worksheet. Let me know!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim trigger As Range
    Set trigger = Range("E18")

    If Intersect(ActiveCell, trigger) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not (Intersect(ActiveCell, trigger) Is Nothing) Then
        Range("C18").Value = "Here is the text I want"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I copy paste your text and it's not working :( nothing happens again. This code is in a "module", should I move it to the particular worksheet ? And what about the '''"option explicit"'''

Comment: This is my "full module" code I have atm, maybe the function is causing some problems ? `Function LastSavedTimeStamp() As Date
  LastSavedTimeStamp = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function


Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim trigger As Range
    Set trigger = Range("E18")

    If Intersect(ActiveCell, trigger) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not (Intersect(ActiveCell, trigger) Is Nothing) Then
        Range("C18").Value = "Here is the text I want"
    End If

End Sub`

Comment: The way I used my code was:
Right click worksheet tab -> View Code. Then from the two dropdowns. 1)
Select Worksheet and 2)
Select SelectionChange. Then Paste Code in body